# Books/Resources about taxonomy learning?

Tags: nlp, books

Taxonomy learning is the task of hierarchically classifying concepts in an automatic manner from text corpora.

I am looking for useful books about taxonomy learning. If they don't exist, I'm open to other kind of resources (papers, videos, links). So far I have only found the following:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_taxonomy_construction
- https://enterprise-knowledge.com/natural-language-processing-and-taxonomy-design/
- https://github.com/sebastianruder/NLP-progress/blob/master/english/taxonomy_learning.md

Any help is greatly appreciated.